# mysql query to sqlalchemy version

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Myself getting familiar with sqlalchemy.I have a mysql query as below:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total, SUM( IF(sub =  'N', 1, 0 ) ) AS NotSubscribed, SUM( IF( subscription =  'A', 1, 0 ) ) AS 12Month, SUM( IF( subscription =  'HY', 1, 0 ) ) AS 6Month, SUM( IF( subscription =  'M', 1, 0 ) ) AS 1Month
FROM accounts
WHERE userID IS NOT NULL
```

I am trying to write a sqlalchemy version of it.

```
  users = Table('users',metadata,autoload=True)
  userInfo = users.select([func.count(users.c.userID).label('Total'),
                              func.sum(users.c.sub == 'N').label('NotSubscribed'),
                              func.sum(users.c.sub == 'A').label('12Month'),
                              func.sum(users.c.sub =='HY').label('6Month'),
                              func.sum(users.c.sub == 'M').label('1Month')]).where(users.c.userID != None).execute()
```

I am ending up with following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object or string expected
```

Can someone help me where I am going wrong. If not let me know if there are any good tutorials about sqlalchemy apart from the documentation.

Thanks

Comment: What is the `SUM( IF(..., 1, 0))` supposed to do here? Total counts for the various subscription types?

Comment: hi, bascially i am trying to get the total users against the different subscribed users.Am i clear

Comment: Why not just use `SELECT subscription, COUNT(userID) FROM accounts WHERE userID IS NOT NULL GROUPBY subscription`, and make `total` the sum of the resulting rows? That query will be much lighter on the query engine too.

Comment: In any case, `func.sum(users.c.subscription == 'N')` would not translate to the `IF()` statement here. You'd have to add a `func.if()` too.

Comment: thanks for that. Just trying to get familiar with sqlalchemy, havent thought of optimising it.cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sum` is the problem in your code. To make it work, you will need to combine `sum` and `case`. Below shows 2 ways of using [`case`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) (pick one you like better):

```
qry = select([
        func.count(users.c.userID).label("Total"),
        func.sum(case(value=users.c.sub, whens={'N': 1}, else_=0)).label("NotSubscribed"),
        func.sum(case(value=users.c.sub, whens={'A': 1}, else_=0)).label("12Month"),
        func.sum(case([(users.c.sub == 'HY', 1)], else_=0)).label("6Month"),
        func.sum(case([(users.c.sub == 'M', 1)], else_=0)).label("1Month"),
    ],
).where(users.c.userID != None)

res = engine.execute(qry)
print res.keys()     # column names
print res.fetchone() # values
```

However, I would indeed consider the recommendation of Martijn, the corresponding SA expression for which would be:

```
qry = select([users.c.sub, func.count(users.c.userID)]).where(users.c.userID != None).group_by(users.c.sub)

res = engine.execute(qry)
rows = res.fetchall()
rows.append(('Total', sum(_r[1] for _r in rows))) # add Total
for row in rows:
    print row
```